# Absolute div jiggles or disappears over Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I want a div to hover over a map made with Google Maps API.

However, when the floating div reaches the map's zoom icons it starts to jiggle, distort or sometimes dissappar.

Any idea as to why this happens and how I should go about fixing it?

I've tried setting the z-index high. but the problem still occurs.

Here is a the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ew56tkv/2/

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.mainWrap
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.map
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.navigation
{
   width:inherit;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:99999;
    background-color:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainWrap">
        <div class="mainIntro">
        <p class="year" id="yearTitle"></p>

        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
                <div> menu option </div>
                <div> menu option </div>
                <div> menu option </div>

            </div>
        <div id="mainMap" class="map">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:100%;">x</div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
            var mapZoom = 10; 
            var mapCenterLat = 41.82454868;
            var mapCenterLon = -87.6341629;
            var map;




        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 


        function initialize() {

            var map_canvas = document.getElementById('mainMap');    
            var map_options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCenterLat,mapCenterLon),
                zoom: mapZoom, 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
            };  

            //Draw the map 
            map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

            //Activate overlay
            var OverlayMap = new MyOverlay({map: map}); 

        } //End initialize()
$(window).scroll(function() { 

                    var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();
                    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    var bottomScroll = windowHeight-scrollBar; 
                    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollLeft()  
            var navigationPosition = $('.navigation').offset(); 

        var navigationWidth = $('.navigation').width(); 

    if (scrollBar > navigationPosition.top) { 
                    $('.navigation').css({
                        position: 'fixed', 
                        top: '0px', 
                    }); //end css changes
                    $('.navigation').css("width",navigationWidth); 

                } else { 
                    $('.navigation').css("position","absolute"); 
                    }; //end else   
});//end scroll function
```

Comment: You can set the position of `.navigation` as `fixed` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ew56tkv/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I set position:fixed i the css and the javascript function, and it works fine now! Can you explain why fixed works over absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the flicker is because you are calculating the position of the `.navigation` div on window scroll. So remove that code and just give `position:fixed` to the `.navigation` div in css. Which will force the `div` to be fixed to the window.

Please note the fixed div will be relative to the window and not to its relative parent.

In the demo I have just given `!important` to the position css to override the dynamic value.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ew56tkv/3/)

Hope this helps.